# Convert raw YUV422 image to RGB

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rgb, yuv

I have a raw image in a yuv422 encoding that I extracted from a csi_camera on my Jetson Nano and I want to convert it to RGB encoding to use for machine learning. How would I go about it? I've tried using different cvtColor codes in OpenCV but resulting images were still a mess. Is there a way to turn this image to a "normal" color?

Here is the image:
[csi_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEU93.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @wiswasi It looks like `COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY` or `COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUYV`. Please post the image as grayscale `uint8` type (without converting to BGR). I suppose the resolution of the image before conversion supposed to be 1024x288 (not sure). Please post some code, showing what you have tried. When replying, please start your comment with @Rotem.

Comment: The image that you attached holds 24 bits per pixel, so it cannot be a YUV 4:2:2 format.

Comment: Try to film something red, something yellow, something green, something blue, something white, something black (possibly using saturated colours, but last two). It helps debugging. YUV (YCC) and RGB are not so standardized as we think: the above text should help you to see what it is the problem. you use also "raw", so maybe the response curve may not be what you expect (try different gamma corrections).

Comment: @Rotem check the accepted answer, that’s how I solved it!

Comment: @wiswasi If you are happy from the result, I guess the solution is correct. You tagged your question as Python, but the answer is in C++. Note that `COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUY2` converts to BGRA, and not to RGB (or BGR).  `cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imgPtr, "yuv422")->image` is unfamiliar to me, but if it's working, I guess the solution is correct. The color conversion coefficients of `COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUY2` may be inaccurate (not matching you camera), and you may get an unnoticeable "color shift".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to convert the image with the following code:

```
for (rosbag::MessageInstance const m : rosbag::View(bag)) {
// Read only the input topic
if(m.getTopic() == topic) {
  // Create an image pointer to the bag file image messages
  sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr imgPtr = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::Image>();
  // Extract the image frame with yuv422 encoding
  image = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imgPtr, "yuv422")->image;
  // Convert the image frame to a BGR format image
  cvtColor( image, newimage, COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUY2 );

  // Write the new image to the out path
imwrite(final_path, newimage);
  count++;
}
}
```

I had to add the `toCvCopy(imgPtr, “yuv422”)->` to specify the incoming encoding first, then convert to using the YUY2 enum.